# Google App Engine PHP running on mac

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying to run WordPress on Google App Engine.

Following the installation I am missing where the "path to php-cgi" is?

I can find some php54-cgi under macport/software/php54-cgi, but setting the path to this gives permission errors.

Also the installation missed saying anything about installing python sdk in order to run the dev_appserver.py.

Question is can you even run the hello world on mac and if so how to start the dev_appserver.py?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld

```
Error message:

 dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/opt/local/var/macports/software/php54-cgi /Users/name/GAE/PHPTest 
WARNING  2013-05-21 22:31:10,600 api_server.py:329] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
WARNING  2013-05-21 22:31:10,606 simple_search_stub.py:962] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/6w/2nmsznqj3d7310_lp70p34s00000gn/T/appengine.helloworld/search_indexes
INFO     2013-05-21 22:31:10,609 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49390
INFO     2013-05-21 22:31:10,614 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-05-21 22:31:10,619 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1232, in _loop_adjusting_instances
    self._adjust_instances()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1209, in _adjust_instances
    self._add_instance(permit_warmup=True)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1087, in _add_instance
    expect_ready_request=perform_warmup)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 195, in new_instance
    self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 138, in _check_environment
    env={})
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/safe_subprocess.py", line 61, in start_process
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Thanks
Regards

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, but on Arch Linux. My php-cgi is on the path. In fact if I run `php-cgi helloworld.php` it works perfectly. Any ideas on what the issue is or how I can get more information?

Comment: In fact I think I wasn't specifying the entire path to my php-cgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used macports to get it running, /opt/local/bin/php-cgi54.

./google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/opt/local/bin/php-cgi54 --php_remote_debugging=yes ~/apps/minishell/

However, I'm not sure that your permission denied error is related to not being able to find the php-cgi executable.

Comment: This worked, now I am getting some other errors(failed to open stream: ). Windows Azure WordPress worked no problem.

Comment: i don't know what that means

Comment: Hey Chris, could you describe the other errors you're getting in a new question?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for asking - but I went on using Windows Azure, it was much easier.